# Largest set of matrices that have unique root

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

Does the set of all positive definite matrices is the largest set that one can get unique root?

for all matrices in the set $A \in \mathcal{P}(M_n(\mathbb C))$, for all n, the largest set that every matrix $B \in A$ have **unique** matrix $C \in A$ s.t $C^2=B$ is the set of all positive definite matrices?

and what if the matrix has unique nth root for all n ($C^n=B$)?

Comment: There is a unique matrix B inside $P(M_n(\mathbb{C}))$. Notice that $-B$ is also a root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do better. Take $Z=\{B\in M_n(\mathbb{C})|spectrum(B)\subset T\}$, where $T=\{a+ib\in\mathbb{C}|b\geq 0$ and if $a\leq 0$, then $b>0\}$. Take $C=\exp(1/2\log(B))$ where $\log(.)$ is the principal logarithm.

EDIT. For the $n^{th}$ root, the answer is the same as above.